# Finding headers,copying in same order to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to search by header column in VBA?

Desired goal is when header is found, copy whole column to sheet2. Headers should be copied in order of their appearance in headers column. After 3 columns copied, blank column should be inserted, then next 3, then again blank column, and so on..

I managed to do it when headers are in list. But I am struggling when they are in column, not so experienced in VBA.

[image: i]

Comment: Yes it’s possible. Please post the code you have

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyCols()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow As Long, header As Range, foundHeader As Range, lCol As Long, srcWS As Worksheet, desWS As Worksheet
    Set srcWS = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set desWS = Sheets("Sheet2")
    LastRow = srcWS.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    lCol = desWS.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each header In desWS.Range(desWS.Cells(1, 1), desWS.Cells(1, lCol))
        Set foundHeader = srcWS.Rows(1).Find(header, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not foundHeader Is Nothing Then
            srcWS.Range(srcWS.Cells(2, foundHeader.Column), srcWS.Cells(LastRow, foundHeader.Column)).Copy desWS.Cells(2, header.Column)
        End If
    Next header
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```